# GNU screen. nothing happens when trying to resume session

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a D-LINK nas (Linux 3.2.34 armv7l), where I have screen, compiled from sources. Everything was fine until something happened and now I can't resume the session.
The symptoms are as follows

```
[root@nas:~]$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    13894.tty.NAS   (Detached)
1 Socket in /tmp/screens/S-root.

[root@nas:~]$ screen -r
[root@nas:~]$ screen -r 111
There is no screen to be resumed matching 111.
[root@nas:~]$ screen -r 13894
[root@nas:~]$
```

So, as you can see, the session is detached, but when I "screen -r" nothing happens at all, not even an error message. If i enter the wrong session name however, it correctly says so, but still, nothing happens when I enter the correct session id.

What could it be?

UPD: I've tried all the parameters from the manual, such as "-D -R", "-DRR" etc. The result is not changing

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the action:

```
$ screen -D -R
```

From the `screen(1)` manual page:

```
   -D -R   Attach  here and now. In detail this means: If a session is running, then reattach. If necessary detach and logout remotely first.  If it was not running create it and notify the user. This is the author's
           favorite.
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing. I've tried everything from the manual

Comment: Does the socket still exist?

Comment: yes, the 'screen -ls' verifies it. also it's physically there